# Navbar buttons not showing up in PFQueryTableViewController (parse + iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uistoryboard

I created a storyboard and added the navbar buttons I want to be displayed[image: storyboard view of PFQueryTableViewController]

But when I simulate my app, this is what I get

[image: no navbar item shows]

I have also tried to programatically add the button using navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(), but that doesn't show up either.

However, when I try the same thing using a normal UIViewController, it works

[image: regular UIViewController]

So my question is if this is the behavior of PFQueryTableViewController, and if so, what do I need to do to correct it?

If more details are needed, I'd be happy to provide them - just curious if anyone has run into this problem before.

**EDIT**

I now have the button showing up on a basic UIViewController using suggestion of @Haidous, but I can't get my PFQueryTableViewController to show up inside it. Here's what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerV: UIView!
    var favoriteVC:FavoritesViewController = FavoritesViewController(className: "Cat")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //?what goes here?
        containerV = favoriteVC.view

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

I'm not sure how to make it show up

******EDIT WITH SOLUTION******

I was able to simply create a container in my storyboard and add my view controller like this (in case anyone else runs into the same problem and stumbles on this question)

```
class WrapperFavoritesViewControllerContainerViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerV: UIView!
var favoriteVC:FavoritesViewController = FavoritesViewController(className: "Cat")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addChildViewController(favoriteVC)
    self.containerV.addSubview(favoriteVC.tableView)
    favoriteVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is because of the PFQueryTableViewController or not.. but a workaround I found was creating a normal View Controller and setting up your Nav Bar there then placing a container view and connecting it to the PFQueryTableViewController thus PFQueryTableViewController becomes the Child View Controller. Hope I helped :)

Comment: If their is anymore needed help please inform me :) I'm currently working on PFQueryTableViewControllers myself. :D

Comment: I edited the post with my new problem. I can't get the PFQueryTableViewController to show up in the container